# Script and DER in P2PKH

Tags: transactions, script, signature, p2pkh

Im trying to figure out the script and DER

In P2PKH, the "first part (scriptsig)" push in stack (`<sig><pubK>`) because is it DER?
Instead  the "second part (scriptPubKey)" you can map the byte on https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script

Or even the first part you can map with script?

Comment: I don't understand the question, please elaborate.